# Display Object in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui

I am working with webservice *GetEmployeebyId*, I get the object data and I would like to display it in a list using javascript in aspx page.

Please help me !!

here my code : it miss the function that display the object

**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/EmployeeService.svc/GetEmployeebyNom/kmjdfb', // Location of the service
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
            datasource:msg
            }
        });
    });
        </script>**
```

my object "msg" is found in this picture [image: Object details]

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery does not have any builtin function to dump JavaScript variables, probably for two reasons: 1) All decent browsers already implement such feature in their developer tools 2) It's completely irrelevant to the end user. What prevents you from building a nicely formatted HTML representation?

Answer (score 0):

The `GetEmployeeByNom` function must shows the employee details, then with your current object:

```
{
    "Adresse": "hcs",
    "CIN": 516515,
    "Competence": "chc",
    "Contract": null,
    "Date_naissance": "Date(1490770800000-0700)/",
    "Email": "jbmkjb@hotmail.fr",
    "Etat_civil": "$Resources:TravelCasrdsFields,Single;",
    "Job_Title": "csv",
    "Nationalite": "hsvcsg",
    "Nom": "sdjhvc",
    "Prenom": "kmjdfb",
    "Sexe": "Mr",
    "Telephone": 65465
}
```

You should try with something like this:

```js
(function() {

  var msg = {
    "Adresse": "hcs",
    "CIN": 516515,
    "Competence": "chc",
    "Contract": null,
    "Date_naissance": "Date(1490770800000-0700)/",
    "Email": "jbmkjb@hotmail.fr",
    "Etat_civil": "$Resources:TravelCasrdsFields,Single;",
    "Job_Title": "csv",
    "Nationalite": "hsvcsg",
    "Nom": "sdjhvc",
    "Prenom": "kmjdfb",
    "Sexe": "Mr",
    "Telephone": 65465
  };

  // Include this function in your code.
  function displayEmployee(msg) {
    var ulList = "";
    ulList += "<ul>";
    for (var property in msg) { // For every property in the msg object.
      if (msg.hasOwnProperty(property)) { // Checks if the property exists.
        ulList += "<li><span>";
        ulList += property; // Gets the property name.
        ulList += "</span>: ";
        ulList += msg[property]; // Gets the property value.
        ulList += "</li>";
      }
    }
    ulList += "</ul>";
    return ulList; // Returns the ul tag with the data.
  }

  // Include this line in your success: function(msg) {} part.
  document.getElementById("EmployeeDetail").innerHTML = displayEmployee(msg);
})();
```

```css
#EmployeeDetail ul {
  border: solid 1px #97bcd6;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#EmployeeDetail ul li {
  margin: 10px;
}

#EmployeeDetail ul li span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="EmployeeDetail">

</div>
```

Then, in the code that you have add `document.getElementById("EmployeeDetail").innerHTML = displayEmployee(msg);`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/EmployeeService.svc/GetEmployeebyNom/kmjdfb', // Location of the service
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
    processdata: true,
    success: function(msg) {
      document.getElementById("EmployeeDetail").innerHTML = displayEmployee(msg);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome Raf. If you need more help feel free to ask. Don't forget to accept this answer. :)